# Jenkins takes too long to execute

Tags: python, windows, selenium, build, jenkins

I'm currently building Python regression tests using Jenkins. For some reason, each individual test in the test suite is taking approx. 15 minutes to run (and there are about 70/80 tests total) in Jenkins, but when I run the tests from the command line on the same windows box, each individual tests takes only about 30seconds to 1minute to run. I even put print statements in some of the files and none of them show up on the jenkins command line output. 
Has anyone else faced this problem or have any suggestions?

Thanks

Also, I'm not doing a sync every time I build, only syncing once!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have to do with running Jenkins in the background (and/or as a service). Try running it in the foreground with `java -jar jenkins.war` an see if it helps.

Comment: This was correct!! Once I brought it to the foreground it ran smoothly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check load on the machine and ensure you set Jenkins with enough memory to run those tests.

It is not clear if you are working with Jenkins-slaves or directly on the master -
This may also have an affect on performance.